# How can I get blank radio button options using collection_radio_buttons in the simple-form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, simple-form

I have this piece of code in a rails view which uses the simple-form gem:

```
<%= simple_form_for :beta_signup, :url => url_for(:action => 'update', :controller => 'survey'), :html => { :id => 'info-form' } do |beta_signup| %>
<%=   beta_signup.collection_radio_buttons :this_excited, [[0,'Not really excited at all'], [1,''], [2, ''], [3, ''], [4, 'Super Excited!!']], :first, :last, :checked => 2, required: false %>
<% end %>
```

And instead of displaying blanks for the middle radio buttons, it displays "This excited 1", "This excited 2", "This excited 3". Is there a way to get the middle 3 radio buttons to display no label?

Putting in " " doesn't work (displays "This excited 1"), and " ", and "\t" don't work (displays " " and "\t" respectively).

Comment: Interesting idea, but I want some radio button labels to be visible. How would I discriminate?

Comment: Not sure, but did you try putting `[1, nil], [2, nil], [3, nil]`?

Comment: Good guess SybariteManoj, but I just got "This excited 1", etc. again.